# Android notification intent not received because activity finishes too soon

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, notifications, android-pendingintent

I am creating an app for android and how i have set it up is that i have a login activity thats lets you login, but it also checks if you have a saved token first and if it does immediately starts the main activity and finishes, so to the user it looks like they were taken straight into that app. Then in the main activity i make a call to make sure the key is still good, and if it passes nothing happens but if it doesn't the user is logged out.

So here is the issue
This works really well except for when i get to the notifications. I have set the pending intent to launch the login activity because thats what the flow of my app starts with but the issue is, onNewIntent never gets hit because if the user is logged the login activity finishes as soon as it is created, thus not allowing me to pass it on the main activity where i would like to handle the logic. Whats the correct course of action here? should i have the notification just launch the main activity? i would like to avoid that because i would have to redo a lot some of the logic of my app.
my app already works as wanted. if someone opens the notification while in my app the notification bar is just dismissed. and nothing happens, and if they are outside the app it launches the login activity and correctly starts the app.

creating the notification inside my service:

```
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent i = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        i.putExtra("type",type);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.microphone_notififcation_icon)
                        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setContentTitle("YapTap")
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                        .setTicker(msg)
                        .setNumber(num)
                        .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

in my login activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(userLoggedIn())
    {   //if user is logged in start next activity and finish
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i);
        finish()
    }
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    //Notification intent received here correctly
}
```

Comment: You should post some relevant code. I'm not sure I understand where `onNewIntent()` should be called here and why this is causing you problems. You also need to consider what should happen if your app is already running (maybe the login activity is being shown, maybe the main activity is shown, maybe some other activity is shown) and your user selects a notification which launches your app. What should happen then?

Comment: I can't see how `onNewIntent()` will ever be called. Once the user is logged in you start `MainActivity` and finish `LoginActivity`. If a user now returns to the app from a notification, it will just create a new instance of `LoginActivity`.

Comment: @DavidWasser know thats the problem. it never gets hit, so i am wondering what the correct course of action is to somehow allow the app to get the notification intent. or do i have to restructure my app